# Background color exceeds parent element setted with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, background-color, border-radius

I'm making an interactive eye which follows the mouse cursor. I've got some specific positions where the border of the eyes are overflowing the parent border limit.

The bug with my current code is here:
I thought the bug is between the **ball and eye CSS classes**:
https://jsfiddle.net/837e6tc1/

The HTML:

```
<div class="eyes">
  <div class="centered">
    <div id="eye-left" class="eye">
      <div id="left-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball" style="left: 49.2734%; top: 94.7467%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="eye-right" class="eye">
      <div id="right-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball" style="left: 49.2734%; top: 94.7467%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.ball{
  width: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #64642d;
}
.eye{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 125% 0%;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.eyes{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 317px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
}
#eye-right{
  margin: 4px 1px 2px 22px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 29px;
}
#eye-left{
  margin: 0px 30px 3px -1px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
}
.stablish{
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
#left-ball{
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-43%,-57%) rotate(-45deg);
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 12px;
}
#right-ball{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%,-90%) rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  height: 13px;
  width: 36px;
}
```

To see clearly the bug, on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/837e6tc1/) you'll probably have to zoom the result, but here is the imagem with the problem at the bottom of the eyes:
[image]

How can I solve this bug that appears at the bottom without changing the margins, height, width and top / left properties defined?

Edit:
With the javascript code that brings movement to the eyes, most of the positions that the eye is in, the background does not exceed the border of the eye contour, but in the static example of jsfiddle and in some other positions, the bug reported happens. This is the js code:

```
document.onmousemove = function(){
    moveEyes(event);
}

function moveEyes(event){
    let x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth;
    let y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight;
    let xPercent = x + "%";
    let yPercent = y + "%";

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
      balls[i].style.left = xPercent;
      balls[i].style.top = yPercent;
      balls[i].style.transform = "translate(-"+xPercent+",-"+yPercent+");";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you asked this because of understanding questions, but I deleted some of your code and adjusted your eyes in the code. I hope I helped. I just cannot get it to flow in a row instead of a column :(. Here is the code:

```css
.ball{
  width: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #64642d;
}
.eyes{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#eye-right{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 29px;
}
#eye-left{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
}
.eye{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 125% 0%;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="eyes">
  <div class="centered">
    <div id="eye-left" class="eye">
      <div id="left-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="eye-right" class="eye">
      <div id="right-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to keep the top and left style inline in ball class, because the ball moves according to mouse cursor. The example I gave here is static to facilitate visualising the exact point of the bug

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I actually found out how to make it flow like a row. I rotated each part. Here is new code:

```css
.ball{
  width: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #64642d;
}
.eyes{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#eye-right{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 29px;
}
#eye-left{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
}
.eye{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 125% 0%;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="eyes">
  <div class="centered">
    <div id="eye-left" class="eye">
      <div id="left-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="eye-right" class="eye">
      <div id="right-ball" class="stablish">
        <div class="ball"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be my question didn't be clear. The demo I gave here is in a static way. My full version have a javascript which makes the ball class moving inside the class of eye. My problem is that at some specific positions of ball (acording to the inline style top/left i gave) the ball exceeds the border radius i specified at eye class. Now I make it more clear?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @alexandre9865 oh I am sorry about that. That I sadly do not know how to fix. I hope some of my code helps.

Answer (score -2):

run this code it will do it

```css
.ball{
  width: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #64642d;
}
.eye{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 125% 0%;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.eyes{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 317px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
}
#eye-right{
  margin: 4px 1px 2px 22px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 29px;
}
#eye-left{
  margin: 0px 30px 3px -1px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
}
.stablish{
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
#left-ball{
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-43%,-57%) rotate(-45deg);
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 17px;
}
#right-ball{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%,-90%) rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  height: 17px;
  width: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="eyes">
      <div class="centered">
        <div id="eye-left" class="eye">
          <div id="left-ball" class="stablish">
            <div class="ball" style="left: 49.2734%; top: 94.7467%"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="eye-right" class="eye">
          <div id="right-ball" class="stablish">
            <div class="ball" style="left: 49.2734%; top: 94.7467%"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you change only the height in stablish class? It's not the problem. When we change the height, the problem  I've showed still happens, but in another specific position of ball class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).